# MongoDB - How to $slice a sub-subarray

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pymongo

Given a document like

```
{
    data:{
        '2015':['a', 'b', 'c', ...],     //<array of n datapoints>
        '2016':['d', 'e', 'f', ...],     //<array of n datapoints>
    },

    someOtherField: {...}
}
```

I am trying to query a slice of one of the arrays within `data` in the following way:

```
db.collection.find({}, {'data.2015':{'$slice': [3, 5]})
```

The query returns the entire `data` field. Does that mean I can't `$slice` a sub-subarray?

What would be the correct way to get a `$slice` of the `data.2015` array?

**Solution**

```
db.collection.find({}, {'data':0, 'someOtherField':0, 'data.2015':{'$slice': [3, 5]})
```

If someone knows how to elegantly suppress **all** other `someOtherField` that would improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$slice is returning an entire data field, but with a slices array.

I setup a similar environment to yours and this is what I got.

Without slice:

```
> db.collection.findOne({})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584917b47778f75d3e0c96db"),
    "data" : {
        "2015" : [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8
        ]
    }
}
```

With slice:

```
> db.collection.findOne({}, {'data.2015' : {$slice: [0, 2]}})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584917b47778f75d3e0c96db"),
    "data" : {
        "2015" : [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
}
```

It returns the entire data object, including other fields it might have, but the 2015 array is spliced from the 0 element plus 2.

If you only want the 2015 array from the data, you can do the following query:

`> db.collection.find({}, {'data': 0, 'data.2015' : {$slice: [0, 2]}})`

Comment: That's right, the array is correctly sliced but everything else is incuded. Adding {'data':0} solves it

Comment: Yeah :) I just edited my answer, I suggested adding `{'data.2015': 1'}` that way you'll ONLY get the data.2015 sliced array

Comment: Actually, I get an error with the double-projection you're using? "TypeError: skip must be an instance of int"

Comment: You were right the 1st time @Pythonic. I got something confused. the final query that actually works is:
`db.collection.find({}, {'data': 0, 'data.2015' : {$slice: [0, 2]}})` answer edited.