# MongoDB - Complex $slicing with inclusions and exclusions

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, pymongo

Given a timeseries document like the one below

```
{
    data:{
        '2015':['a', 'b', 'c', ...],     //<array of n datapoints>
        '2016':['d', 'e', 'f', ...],     //<array of n datapoints>
    },

    otherFieldA: {...}
    otherFieldB: {...}
}
```

To get a slice of `2015` I would use the following projection as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034708/mongodb-how-to-slice-a-sub-subarray):

```
myProjection = {'data':0, 'otherFieldA':0, 'otherFieldB':0, 'data.2015':{'$slice': [3, 5]}}

db.collection.find({}, myProjection)
```

Now let's suppose I **also** want to get also **all** of `2016`

- **Option A**: adding `'data.2016':1` in the projection above gets a classic [inclusion + exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949544/mongodb-cant-canonicalize-query-badvalue-projection-cannot-have-a-mix-of-incl) mongo error
- **Option B**: adding another `$slice` to the projection `'data.2016':{'$slice': <len of data.2016>}` works but might be time inefficient as mongo needs to scroll down the `data.2016` array rather than just scooping up the entire array. Also, I would need to know the lenght of `data.2016`, which is not a given

**Is there a third option to get a slice of `data.2015` and all of `data.2016`, while excluding all the `otherField` values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with the aggregation framework using $project:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
         "data.2015":{
            $slice:[
               "$data.2015",
               1,
               1
            ]
         },
         "data.2016":"$data.2016"
      }
   }
])
```

output will be :

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("58492f23f2e6a23e2168649d"),
   "data":{
      "2015":[
         "b"
      ],
      "2016":[
         "d",
         "e",
         "f"
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What kind of performance impact should I expect vs a plain find with projection? (if any)

Comment: I guess there's no real difference, but it's hard to tell with the info you provided.  If you are really concerned about performance, take a look at the explain() output of both query so you can see what is actually happening